# GROUP_CONCAT (CONCAT... em Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Não sei se alguém me consegue ajudar necessitava de executar está `SQL` no Laravel só que não sei como usar o `GROUP_CONCAT` com o `CONCAT` dentro?

```
select dictionaries.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{name:"', dictionary_files.name, '", file:"',dictionary_files.path,'"}')) as files
from dictionaries  
join dictionary_files on dictionaries.`id` = dictionary_files.`dictionary_id`
Where dictionary_files.name Like "Teste%" Group by dictionaries.name
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente com [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries):

```
$dictionaries = DB::table('dictionaries')
  ->select(DB::raw('dictionaries.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("{name:",dictionary_files.name,"file:",dictionary_files.path,"}")) as files'))
  ->where('dictionary_files.name', 'LIKE', "Teste%")
  ->groupBy('dictionaries.name')
  ->get();
```

***Observação:*** tinha também concatenção errada, aspas fora do lugar, mas, com [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries) vai resolver seu problema.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries)
- [Database: Query Builder - Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-expressions)